# Unexpected change in image src in react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating react app and I am stuck on a this problem, I have created a high order component called layout that is transferring two components header and footer components to other components. Both the header and footer components have a image logo that are set to link to home page using react-router-dom links, I have included the image source in each using the src keyword as follows `<img alt="" src="images/eplogo.png"/>` which is working as expected but the problem comes when the route changes from home (http://localhost:3000/) to another route let say http://localhost:3000/articles or http://localhost:3000/videos my image src is changes to that route instead of `<img alt="" src="images/eplogo.png"/>` it now points to `<img alt="" src="article/images/eplogo.png"/>` or `<img alt="" src="videos/images/eplogo.png"/>` the change cause the image logo not to appear on this other component and when I inspect this through the browser I can see the changes but the changes are not on my actual file code, a sample of my code is as follow

**MY HEADER**

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = (props) => {

    return (
        <header
        <Link to="/" className="logo">
            <img
                alt=""
                src="images/eplogo.png"
            />
        </Link>
        </header>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

**MY FOOTER**

```
import React from 'react';
import './footer.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CURRENT_YEAR } from '../../config';

const Footer = () => (
<div className="footer">
    <Link to="/" className="logo">
        <img
            alt=""
            src="images/eplogo.png"
        />
    </Link>
    <div className="rights">© PREMIER LEAGUE {CURRENT_YEAR}</div>
</div>
);

export default Footer;
```

**MY LAYOUT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './layout.css';
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/footer';

class Layout extends Component {
    state = {
    };
   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <Header
               />
               {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Layout;
```

**MY ROUTER** (from where I am calling the routes)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home/Home';
import Layout from './Hoc/Layout/layout';
import NewsArticle from './Components/Articles/News/Post/index';

class Routes extends Component {
    state = {};
    render() {
        return (
           <Layout>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/articles/:id" exact component={NewsArticle} />
               </Switch>
           </Layout>
       );
   }
}
export default Routes;
```

what could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to `react-router-dom`.  This is just the way that web paths work.
`src="images/eplogo.png"` is a [relative path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls) which is relative to the current URL.  It takes the current URL and adds `"images/eplogo.png"` to it.

You want an absolute path so you need a `/` at the start of the `src`.  `<img alt="" src="/images/eplogo.png"/>`.  An absolute path starts from the root of your domain (`http://localhost:3000/`) rather than from the current URL.

Comment: thanks it absolutely worked I did add the ' / ' and all was well. I am very glad you actually understood my troubles, I appreciate it